# Can I get the required route in an Elmah filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a very specific action I do not want Elmah to handle because it can emit 500 response status code as part of its normal functionning.

I don't want to be spammed by the errors that occur in this route, but I also don't want to shut down Elmah logging 500 errors everywhere else.

Is there any way to do this declaratively in the web.config, or do I have to write my own [Assertion](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering#Writing_Your_Own_Assertion)?
Or, to rephrase, is there any way to get the route with a binding in a test assertion?

PS: for those who wonder why on earth I would allow my action to generate a 500, it's because it's a wrapper around customer defined code, and I want my customers to know immediately if their custom code is buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are letting unhandled exceptions to be raised from that particular action. I guess so because if you just return a 500 error code without an exception, Elmah is not logging it:

```
public ActionResult ThrowError()
{
    //your wrapper calling customer code        

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Buggy code");
}
```

So I am assuming your action is throwing unhandled exceptions (possibly so your customers can see the exception details?). Let´s say your action method is in the `HomeController` and looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ThrowError()
{    
    //your wrapper calling customer code
    // the customer code throws an exception: 
    throw new Exception("Buggy code");
}
```

Every time you go to `/Home/ThrowError` you will get an unhandled exception that results in a 500 and is logged by Elmah. So you need to filter this from Elmah, which gives you [the following options](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering)

You could add the following filter for Elmah on your `global.asax`, telling Elmah to ignore exceptions on that particular url:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if(httpContext == null) return;

    if (httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/home/throwerror") e.Dismiss();
}
```

If you have enabled the `ErrorFilter` module, you can do the same in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

<elmah>
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <and>
          <equal binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" value="/home/throwerror" type="String" />
          <!--You could also use a regex for the url-->
          <!--<regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']"
                  pattern="/home/throwerror\d*" />-->
        </and>
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

I don´t really like this approach which depends on listing all urls where you want to filter the exceptions (Or making sure all this urls follow a pattern you can express on a regex). If you can wrap exceptions thrown from the customer code into a specific exception, you could then filter all unhandled exceptions of that type no matter which url are they thrown from.

So you could create a new exception type and use it in your code wrapping customer´s code:

```
public class CustomerException : Exception
{
    public CustomerException(Exception e)
        : base(e.Message, e)
    {
    }
}

public ActionResult ThrowError()
{
    try
    {
        //your wrapper calling customer code
        // the customer code throws an exception: 
        throw new Exception("Buggy code");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new CustomerException(e);
    }
}
```

Now you can filter those exceptions from being logged in Elmah either in `global.asax` or `web.config`:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if(httpContext == null) return;

    if (e.Exception is CustomerException) e.Dismiss();
}

<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <jscript>
      <expression>
        <![CDATA[
        // @assembly mscorlib
        // @assembly WebApplication3
        // @import WebApplication3.Controllers

        // In my dummy project, CustomerException is located in WebApplication3.Controllers
        $.Exception instanceof CustomerException
        ]]>
      </expression>
    </jscript>
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

Now with the last approach you don´t depend on the action urls.

Hope this helps!